# Change <body> ID with Javascript from within ContentPage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I'm looking to do a short term hack on a site.  The site is a ASP.NET site with a master page.  The body tag is in the master page.   I'd like to specify which ID should be in the body tag from within various content pages.  What I don't know is if you can have this type of access to the body tag when your JS is within the body tag.  For various reasons, I'd like to try to accomplish this in JS, not .NET.

Any tips?

Rephrasing for clarity:

I would like to use JavaScript to specify a body ID from within the body tag of a site. For example:

```
<body id="MyID">

JS to change MyID to another name

</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you rephrase it to make it clearer?

Comment: Your wording doesn't make it sound like you specifically want to dynamically change the ID on the client side. Unless you need to do this, don't use JavaScript, but set it on the server side

Comment: @Matti If you were familiar with master pages you would better understand the predicament

Comment: @Josh: I am familiar with master pages and they are *no* excuse to use client script for something that obviously doesn't need client script. Besides, if your service side platform is preventing you from building your page correctly (which it isn't in this case, though), you should probably consider another platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the Page_Load of any ContentPage...

```
string JS = "document.body.id = 'WhateverID';";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "BodyID", JS, true);
```